Contour integration over lower half of complex plane
I need to perform this integration as a contour integral over the lower half of the complex omega plane with Mathematica.
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-i \left(\omega -\omega _0\right) (t-\tau )}}{\lambda ^2+\left(\omega _0-\omega \right){}^2} \, d\omega$$
I am new to Mathematica and have no idea on how to proceed.

Welcome to Mathematica SE!  This site is generally not a tutorial site.  If you are just learning Mathematica, I recommend following some online tutorials.  The Mathematica documentation is very good, so you can also jump right in by looking up Integrate in the documentation.  In there, you will see many examples of proper syntax, and there should be examples doing contour integration as well. Alternatively, you can look up Residue in order to compute the integral using direct residue integration rather than computing the contour.

Mathematica "knows" how to compute this integral without the need of integration over the complex plane. Just type  Integrate[Exp[-I*ω*t]/(λ^2+ω^2),{ω,-∞,∞}, Assumptions -> Element[λ|t,Reals]] and you will get the correct result. Complex path integration is needed if you would like to compute the integral "by hands". If you want to learn this technique, you have to attend a course in complex analysis or read a textbook. It does not bring much to learn it from some online resources.

@yarchik: The general case is not so simple. Integrate[  Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*     t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2), {\[Omega], -Infinity,    Infinity},   Assumptions ->    t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals && \[Lambda] > 0] results in a long analytic expression in terms of SinIntegral ans CosIntegral.

@march: Did you try to apply Residue yourself?

@user64494 Yes, you are right. Every time I see such questions, I do not know what to do. On one side I am tempted to provide quick and relevant answer that may be expected in some contexts. People want such quick and easy solutions. But it is much more important to advise that one does not learn math from a forum. One learns by attending a course or by reading a book. Therefore, I believe such questions are out of scope of this site and should be closed.

@yarchik: The contour integration in the case under consideration may be useful for didactic purpose.

The lower half plane is, well, planar, and not a path or contour; that is, 2 dimensional and not 1 dimensional. Do you mean a path in the lower half plane? What path? Typically $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots$ indicates an integral over the real line (or real axis in the complex plane). Sometimes one integrates over the oriented boundary of semicircle and lets the radius approach infinity — do you mean something like that?

Computing integral  NOT using Contour integration.
Using InverseFourierTransform we can get a simple solution:
ComplexExpand[FullSimplify[Sqrt[2 Pi] E^(I  t  \[Omega]0)*
InverseFourierTransform[1/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega]0 - \[Omega])^2), \[Omega], t, 
 Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals],
Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals] // Expand]

(*(E^(t \[Lambda]) \[Pi] Sign[\[Lambda]] UnitStep[-t Sign[
 Re[\[Lambda]]]])/\[Lambda] + (
E^(-t \[Lambda]) \[Pi] Sign[\[Lambda]] UnitStep[
t Sign[Re[\[Lambda]]]])/\[Lambda]*)

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-i (\omega -\text{$\omega $0}) t)}{\lambda ^2+(\text{$\omega $0}-\omega )^2} \, d\omega =\frac{e^{t \lambda } \pi  \text{sgn}(\lambda ) \theta (-t
   \text{sgn}(\Re(\lambda )))}{\lambda }+\frac{e^{-t \lambda } \pi  \text{sgn}(\lambda ) \theta (t \text{sgn}(\Re(\lambda )))}{\lambda }$$
where: $t=t-\tau$
Check:
F1[\[Omega]0_, \[Lambda]_, t_] := (E^(t \[Lambda]) \[Pi] Sign[\[Lambda]] UnitStep[-t Sign[
   Re[\[Lambda]]]])/\[Lambda] + (
E^(-t \[Lambda]) \[Pi] Sign[\[Lambda]] UnitStep[
 t Sign[Re[\[Lambda]]]])/\[Lambda];

G1[\[Omega]0_, \[Lambda]_, t_] := NIntegrate[
Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*
  t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2), {\[Omega], \
-Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

 par = SetPrecision[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 100], 21];
 Chop[Table[{F1[par[[n]], par[[n]], par[[n]]] - G1[par[[n]], par[[n]], par[[n]]]}, {n, 1, Length[par]}]] // Flatten // Quiet

 (*0,0,.....0 *)
 (*Solution is correct. *)


The title of the question is "Contour integration over lower half of complex plane". You find the integral under consideration without any contour integration or residues. Also the question arises: how does InverseFourierTransform[1/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega]0 - \[Omega])^2), \[Omega], t,   Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals], Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals] work?

It is not so simple because of many parameters (which are assumed real). Unfortunately,
ContourIntegrate[ Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*
t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2), \[Omega] \[Element] 
HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {0, -1}],
Assumptions ->  t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals &&   R > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0]

returns the input. In view of it we consider
j = -ContourIntegrate[Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*
t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2), \[Omega] \[Element] 
 Disk[{0, 0}, R, {Pi, 2*Pi}], Assumptions -> 
 t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals && 
R > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0]


ConditionalExpression[-Piecewise[{{((-1 + E^(2*t*\[Lambda]))*Pi)/(E^(t*\[Lambda])*\[Lambda]),  Abs[\[Lambda] + I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1 && Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0 &&  Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1 && Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0},  {-(Pi/(E^(t*\[Lambda])*\[Lambda])), Abs[\[Lambda] + I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1 &&  Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}, {(E^(t*\[Lambda])*Pi)/\[Lambda],  Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1 && Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}}, 0],  (R != Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0] || Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] >= 0) &&  (R != Abs[\[Lambda] + I*\[Omega]0] || Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] >= 0) &&  !((Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0]/R <= 1 && (Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] == Pi ||  Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] == 0)) || (Abs[\[Lambda] + I*\[Omega]0]/R <= 1 &&  (Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] == Pi || Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] == 0)))]

We may assume Abs[\[Lambda] + I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1 because R will tend to infinity:
j = -ContourIntegrate[Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*
 t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2), \[Omega] \[Element] 
   Disk[{0, 0}, R, {Pi, 2*Pi}], Assumptions ->  t \[Element] Reals &&
 \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals && R > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && Abs[\[Lambda] + I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1]


ConditionalExpression[-Piecewise[{{((-1 + E^(2*t*\[Lambda]))*Pi)/(E^(t*\[Lambda])*\[Lambda]),  Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0 && Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1 &&  Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}, {-(Pi/(E^(t*\[Lambda])*\[Lambda])),  Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}, {(E^(t*\[Lambda])*Pi)/\[Lambda],  Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1 && Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}}, 0],  (R != Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0] || Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] >= 0) &&  Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi && Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != 0 &&  (Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi || Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0]/R > 1)]

Now
FullSimplify[j, Assumptions -> Abs[\[Lambda] - I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1]


-ConditionalExpression[Piecewise[ {{(2*Pi*Sinh[t*\[Lambda]])/\[Lambda], Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0 &&  Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}, {-(Pi/(E^(t*\[Lambda])*\[Lambda])),  Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}, {(E^(t*\[Lambda])*Pi)/\[Lambda], Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}},  0], Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi && Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != 0 &&  Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi]

and, tending R to infinity,
Limit[%, R -> Infinity]


ConditionalExpression[-Piecewise[ {{(2*Pi*Sinh[t*\[Lambda]])/\[Lambda], Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0 &&  Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}, {-(Pi/(E^(t*\[Lambda])*\[Lambda])),  Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}, {(E^(t*\[Lambda])*Pi)/\[Lambda], Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}},  0], Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi && Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != 0 &&  Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi]

We can get rid of Arg[-I  \[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != \[Pi] &&  Arg[I  \[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != 0 &&  Arg[I  \[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != \[Pi].
Edit. The minus sign is added since the boundary of the lower half-disk is oriented counterclockwise.
Edi 2. A typo - instead of = in the last ConditionalExpression in the answer.

Just to compare with Integrate[  Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*     t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2), {\[Omega], -Infinity,    Infinity},   Assumptions ->    t \[Element] Reals && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals && \[Lambda] > 0] which outputs a long analytic expression in terms of SinIntegral ans CosIntegral.

As you know, I have a problem with this kind of questions here. These searches for quick and easy answers never work and lead to further confusions of unexperienced pupils or students. Future visitors to this forum will not be able to learn about the MA techniques from this questions unless there are some good and pedagogical answers. Unfortunately, your answer is messy and not quite pedagogical because it does not explain why certain transformations are done.

@yarchik: Can you kindly elaborate "certain transformations", giving us details? I follow a usual approach of complex analysis, integrating over Disk[{0, 0}, R, {Pi, 2*Pi}].

I am not questioning what you are doing. I am concerned that the OP might not even know that the result does not depend on the choice of contour if the function is analytic. Because if they knew, they would be able to find the function poles and residues and/or ask more precise question. Thus, if you would like to be pedagogic, it would be good to briefly explain the relation between the integral over real axis and the contour integral (j  in your notations). Moreover, the half-circle integral will only converge if $t-\tau>0$, you only assume the difference is real.

@yarchik: Thank you for your good point. I think the  lower half-circle integral  converges for each real t, but the Jordan's lemma works for t > 0 only.The reas for my opinion is that Integrate[  Exp[-I*(R*Exp[I*\[Theta]] - \[Omega]0)*t], {\[Theta], Pi, 2*Pi},   Assumptions -> R > 0 && t < 0 && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals] results in E^(I t \[Omega]0) (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[R t]) and the denominator is $O(R^{-2})$.

@yarchik: ContourIntegrate[  Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2), \[Omega] \[Element]    Circle[{0, 0}, R, {Pi, 2*Pi}],  Assumptions ->  t < 0 && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals && R > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 &&  Abs[\[Lambda] + I*\[Omega]0]/R < 1] outputs (1/(2 \[Lambda]))I E^(-t \[Lambda]) (-E^(2 t \[Lambda])       ExpIntegralEi[-t (I R + \[Lambda] - I \[Omega]0)] +     E^(2 t \[Lambda])      ExpIntegralEi[I t (R + I \[Lambda] + \[Omega]0)] +     ExpIntegralEi[t (\[Lambda] + I (-R + \[Omega]0))] -     ExpIntegralEi[t (\[Lambda] + I (R + \[Omega]0))])

and Limit[%,  R -> Infinity,  Assumptions -> t < 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && \[Omega]0 \[Element] Reals] equals (E^(-t \[Lambda]) (-1 + E^(2 t \[Lambda])) \[Pi])/\[Lambda].

Unfortunately, my result for {t -> -1, \[Lambda] -> 2, \[Omega]0 -> 1} equals (E^2 \[Pi])/2 and is not in accordance with NIntegrate[  Exp[-I*(\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)*      t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)^2) /. {t -> -1, \ \[Lambda] -> 2, \[Omega]0 -> 1}, {\[Omega], -Infinity, Infinity}] which performs 0.212584.

In this case the correct result is (E^2 \[Pi])/2 + (   E^(-t \[Lambda]) (-1 + E^(      2 t \[Lambda])) \[Pi])/\[Lambda] /. {t -> -1, \[Lambda] ->     2, \[Omega]0 -> 1} ao we deal with a bug in ContourIntegrate for t < 0.

If my old math skills don't deceive me the contourintegration over the lower half plane of complex omega is evaluted using Residue theorem:

For real  \[Lambda]>0,\[Omega]0 only one singularity \[Omega]0 - \[Lambda] I is enclosed by the contour covering the complex half plane
resi=Residue[Exp[-I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0) t]/(\[Lambda]^2 + (\[Omega] - \
\[Omega]0)^2), {\[Omega], \[Omega]0 - \[Lambda] I}]  
(*(I E^(-t \[Lambda]))/(2 \[Lambda])*)

Contourintegral follows to
2Pi I resi (*-((E^(-t \[Lambda]) \[Pi])/\[Lambda])*)


Something to adjust. -((E^(-t \[Lambda]) \[Pi])/\[Lambda]/.-((E^(-t \[Lambda]) \[Pi])/\[Lambda] results in -(\[Pi]/(2 E^2)), where as

ConditionalExpression[-Piecewise[{{(2*Pi*Sinh[t*\[Lambda]])/\[Lambda],        Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0 &&         Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] <          0}, {-(Pi/(E^(t*\[Lambda])*\[Lambda])),        Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] <         0}, {(E^(t*\[Lambda])*Pi)/\[Lambda],        Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] < 0}}, 0],    Arg[(-I)*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi &&     Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != 0 &&     Arg[I*\[Lambda] + \[Omega]0] != Pi] /. {t -> 1, \[Lambda] ->     2, \[Omega]0 -> Pi/4} and

(E^(t  \[Lambda])  \[Pi]  Sign[\[Lambda]]  UnitStep[-t  Sign[         Re[\[Lambda]]]])/\[Lambda] + (E^(-t  \[Lambda])  \[Pi]  Sign[\ \[Lambda]]  UnitStep[t  Sign[Re[\[Lambda]]]])/\[Lambda] /. {t ->     1, \[Lambda] -> 2} produce \[Pi]/(2 E^2).

What contour $\gamma$ do you mean in your answer?

contour γ is quite arbitrary, should only enclose the residuum \[Omega]0 - \[Lambda] I

So the intersection between the real axis and $\gamma$ may be empty, may not? Are you serious?

I think the residual theorem is serious

Can you kindly explain how you apply the residue theorem in your answer, giving us the details about the contour $\gamma$? Up to you,  the intersection between the real axis and $\gamma$ may be empty.

We can take different contours to get the same value of the contourintegral. Infinite half circle (r->infinity) or a small circle Circle[ {\[Omega]0, - \[Lambda] },dr] /.dr->0 or ...

Standard approach is path $(-\infty,+\infty)$ along real axis and returning to $-\infty$ along a lower semi-circle with $r\to\infty$.  However, to be complete, need to confirm the integral over semi-circle goes to zero, then negate answer since direction is clockwise.

@josh There is no standard approach, You only have to know the pols inside the contour. By the way integration formula QP presents isn't correct I think

@UlrichNeumann: Can you kindly define "Infinite half circle"? I have never met it.  Also how about the difference in sign in answers?

@UlrichNeumann:  I should have said "common approach".  However it's insufficient to just know about the poles inside; still need to address the value of the integral over the remaining legs of the closed contour and in the case of the contour I described above, the  semi-circle, over the contour $re^{it}$

@josh: As yarchik pointed out the Jordan's lemma can be applied only for t > 0.

@josh We don't need Jordan's lemma in this case, Residue Theorem is sufficient
